# Maximo Integration: Putting sub-objects in a response to SOAP

Tags: response, integration, maximo, inbound

Need help! I'm having a problem with putting sub-objects in a response from Maximo to SOAP.

for Example, I want my response to look like this:

```
<mainObject>
   <--Imagine mainObject fields here-->
   <subObject>
       <--Imagine subObject fields here-->
   </subObject>
</mainObject>
```

I can't seem to find any sample from the internet that I can use as a reference.
Can anyone give me some clues/hints?

Comment: Adding a related object to the object structure defined for the server should give you what you are asking. Or is this not a query service response but some other response.  ;)

Comment: Hi Dex! it's you again. It is related to the other question I posted yesterday. The problem is the subobject is still not showing but I noticed that I can modify the response using automation scripts in Maximo. Also, this is not a query service, this is a sync service, as much as I want to use a query service but my requirement is to use a sync service. I did attempt to modify the response by using "irData" in the autoscript and it worked but I need to put a subobject or just put a dummy subobject that will show the data within the real subobject inside of Maximo on the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the method createChildrenData() to create a new sub-object and then add the fields to that. For example:

```
irData.createChildrenData(subObject)
```

I had to decompile the StructureObject class to get that method. You'll need to create a new WSDL for this modified response, otherwise the end point won't recognize the new format.